# How can I use Mac OSX Sierra emoji on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, compatibility

I like Mac's emojis and dislike Windows'.

It seems that competing specs still make various emoji fonts and OS incompatible.

Is there a compatibility conversion project for the "official" emoji character sets? Or at least somewhere to compare and download cross platform emoji fonts?

After a font is installed with emoji character sets, is there a way to tell Windows to use that font only for emoji glyphs?

---

[How do I replace Windows 10's emoji?](https://superuser.com/questions/1062418/how-do-i-replace-windows-10s-emoji) (10k views, people want this!)

[Is is possible to change the emoji set on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/968509/is-is-possible-to-change-the-emoji-set-on-os-x/1079151#1079151)

https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/issues/43

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/06/using-color-fonts-beautiful-text-icons/

Comment: Isn't that the same question as the first one you linked, then?

Comment: No. They are asking about Noto Color Emoji which uses a different spec than Apple's emoji. Maybe this one is possible without 13 risky steps.

Comment: If the problem is to use a Mac font on Windows, see these solutions : (1) [article1](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-mac-dfont-to-ttf/) about using [DfontSplitter](https://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter), (2) Use [Macdisk](https://www.macdisk.com/fontsen.php), (3) Use [Fondu](http://fondu.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: one thing to keep in mind is that (at least on mobile, not sure about desktop), you using the set of emoji doesn't mean the receiver receives the same emoji. Personally, I miss the older google emoji.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is much too broad - Windows contains many Microsoft applications,
but you most probably have also installed some third-party applications.
The integration between all these applications is usually non-existent,
so the problem of emojis is better analyzed in the context of the applications
in which you would like to use them.

If you would like to use the emojis in writing, this means using the corresponding
Mac font on Windows. You could use for that one of the following tools :
[DfontSplitter](https://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter)
([description](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-mac-dfont-to-ttf/)),
[Macdisk](https://www.macdisk.com/fontsen.php),
[Fondu](http://fondu.sourceforge.net/).

However, even if you ported these fonts to your computer under Windows,
they will still only exist on your computer.
If you would wish to use them for communicating with other people,
you would need to include them in the sent document.
Embedding fonts is possible for Word documents or PowerPoint presentations
(see [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/106681/how-to-embed-fonts-in-a-microsoft-word-document/)),
and is also possible for PDF documents
(see [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html)),
but only for very few others.

If you are looking for a general solution for using everywhere,
the only one I can think of is to take images of the emojis and use them
in your communications. This is the only general and portable
solution I can think of.

If you are looking for a better solution for use in a specific application,
let us know which application and we will try to help.
However, for many applications the only solution would be that
of using images of the emojis.